# Can't access backoffice, URL returns "umbraco#/umbraco"

Tags: url, content-management-system, umbraco, project

I am unable to access the Umbraco backoffice after including/excluding some files in my project and deleting the files in the "Temporary ASP.NET Files" folder.

When i go to my localhost/umbraco i am just met with a blank page and umbraco replaced with "umbraco#/umbraco" in the URL.

How can i resolve this issue?

Comment: Try resolving your BRowser cach and logging in over the Umbraco UI again. the Hash is pmost likely chached

Answer (score 0):

The same issue happens to me and it was fixed by clearing browser cache.